# Use group by logic with lapply function

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, lapply

I can use the following the function "tabyl" form the janitor package like this to apply tabyl to every column.

```
lapply(mtcars[,2:4],tabyl)
```

What I really want to do is use group by cyl and then use tabyl to those all those specified columns,something like this (does not work):

```
lapply(mtcars[,2:4],tabyl(cyl))
```

How would I put this above line into an lapply function? Or is there some other way of grouping and using a group by logic?

Please note, I have hundreds of variables in my actual data, and I want to apply tabyl to almost all the variables in my data (all the numeric at least). So I need a way of calling tabyl on them without explicitly calling on the variable names!

I want it to look like this(provided in an answer below), except I want to include MANY more variables. Imagine mtcars has 104 variables, and I want to apply this group tabyl on only the numeric ones.

```
    cyl                             
            4           6         8         
            n   Percent n Percent n  Percent
 disp 71.1   1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
      75.7   1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
      78.7   1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
      79     1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
      95.1   1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
      108    1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
      120.1  1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
      120.3  1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
      121    1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
      140.8  1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
      145    0    0.000 1  14.29   0   0.000
      146.7  1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
      160    0    0.000 2  28.57   0   0.000
      167.6  0    0.000 2  28.57   0   0.000
      225    0    0.000 1  14.29   0   0.000
      258    0    0.000 1  14.29   0   0.000
      275.8  0    0.000 0   0.00   3  21.429
      301    0    0.000 0   0.00   1   7.143
      304    0    0.000 0   0.00   1   7.143
      318    0    0.000 0   0.00   1   7.143
      350    0    0.000 0   0.00   1   7.143
      351    0    0.000 0   0.00   1   7.143
      360    0    0.000 0   0.00   2  14.286
      400    0    0.000 0   0.00   1   7.143
      440    0    0.000 0   0.00   1   7.143
      460    0    0.000 0   0.00   1   7.143
      472    0    0.000 0   0.00   1   7.143
      All   11  100.000 7 100.00  14 100.000
 hp   52     1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
      62     1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
      65     1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
      66     2   18.182 0   0.00   0   0.000
      91     1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
      93     1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
      95     1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
      97     1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
      105    0    0.000 1  14.29   0   0.000
      109    1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
      110    0    0.000 3  42.86   0   0.000
      113    1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
      123    0    0.000 2  28.57   0   0.000
      150    0    0.000 0   0.00   2  14.286
      175    0    0.000 1  14.29   2  14.286
      180    0    0.000 0   0.00   3  21.429
      205    0    0.000 0   0.00   1   7.143
      215    0    0.000 0   0.00   1   7.143
      230    0    0.000 0   0.00   1   7.143
      245    0    0.000 0   0.00   2  14.286
      264    0    0.000 0   0.00   1   7.143
      335    0    0.000 0   0.00   1   7.143
      All   11  100.000 7 100.00  14 100.000
```

Comment: `lapply(split(mtcars[2:4], mtcars$cyl), function(x) lapply(x, tabyl))`

Comment: Thanks, but I would prefer to see the group as an additional column for each variable, such as when you run this: mtcars %>% tabyl(gear, carb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to generate counts and frequencies by multiple variables. A solution with `tables::tabular()` enables one to display the "by group" on the column dimension, and other variables on the row dimension of a table.

We'll use the `mtcars` data to display `disp` and `hp` on the row dimension, and `cyl` on the column dimension.

```
library(tables)
tabular(((Factor(disp) + 1) + (Factor(hp) + 1))~(Factor(cyl))*((n=1) + Percent("col")),data = mtcars)
```

...and the output:

```
            cyl                             
            4           6         8         
            n   Percent n Percent n  Percent
 disp 71.1   1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
      75.7   1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
      78.7   1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
      79     1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
      95.1   1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
      108    1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
      120.1  1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
      120.3  1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
      121    1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
      140.8  1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
      145    0    0.000 1  14.29   0   0.000
      146.7  1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
      160    0    0.000 2  28.57   0   0.000
      167.6  0    0.000 2  28.57   0   0.000
      225    0    0.000 1  14.29   0   0.000
      258    0    0.000 1  14.29   0   0.000
      275.8  0    0.000 0   0.00   3  21.429
      301    0    0.000 0   0.00   1   7.143
      304    0    0.000 0   0.00   1   7.143
      318    0    0.000 0   0.00   1   7.143
      350    0    0.000 0   0.00   1   7.143
      351    0    0.000 0   0.00   1   7.143
      360    0    0.000 0   0.00   2  14.286
      400    0    0.000 0   0.00   1   7.143
      440    0    0.000 0   0.00   1   7.143
      460    0    0.000 0   0.00   1   7.143
      472    0    0.000 0   0.00   1   7.143
      All   11  100.000 7 100.00  14 100.000
 hp   52     1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
      62     1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
      65     1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
      66     2   18.182 0   0.00   0   0.000
      91     1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
      93     1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
      95     1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
      97     1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
      105    0    0.000 1  14.29   0   0.000
      109    1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
      110    0    0.000 3  42.86   0   0.000
      113    1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
      123    0    0.000 2  28.57   0   0.000
      150    0    0.000 0   0.00   2  14.286
      175    0    0.000 1  14.29   2  14.286
      180    0    0.000 0   0.00   3  21.429
      205    0    0.000 0   0.00   1   7.143
      215    0    0.000 0   0.00   1   7.143
      230    0    0.000 0   0.00   1   7.143
      245    0    0.000 0   0.00   2  14.286
      264    0    0.000 0   0.00   1   7.143
      335    0    0.000 0   0.00   1   7.143
      All   11  100.000 7 100.00  14 100.000
>
```

### UPDATE: automate the process

In the comments to my answer, the original poster asked how one might automate `tabular()` to avoid having to type out all the variables to be tabulated. We can do this with `lapply()` and an anonymous function.

Since the OP used column numbers as part of their question, we'll create a vector of columns from the `mtcars` data frame to be tabulated. We'll use that as the input to `lapply()`, along with two other arguments, one for the data frame, and another to specify the column variable in the table. Since the column variable will be a single variable, we specified it with its column name rather than a number.

```
# generalize and automate
varList <- 2:4
lapply(varList,function(x,df,byVar){ 
         tabular((Factor(df[[x]],paste(colnames(df)[x])) + 1) ~ ((Factor(df[[byVar]],paste(byVar)))*((n=1) + Percent("col"))),
             data= df) 
  },mtcars,"cyl")
```

The tricky part is how automating the process without the output tables having row headers of `df[[x]]` and column headers of `df[[byVar]]`. To avoid this situation, we extract the column name for the row dimension with `colnames()`, and we overwrite the header for the columns by pasting the `byVar` argument into the header.

...and the output:

```
[[1]]

     cyl                             
     4           6         8         
 cyl n   Percent n Percent n  Percent
 4   11  100     0   0      0   0    
 6    0    0     7 100      0   0    
 8    0    0     0   0     14 100    
 All 11  100     7 100     14 100    

[[2]]

       cyl                             
       4           6         8         
 disp  n   Percent n Percent n  Percent
 71.1   1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
 75.7   1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
 78.7   1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
 79     1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
 95.1   1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
 108    1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
 120.1  1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
 120.3  1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
 121    1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
 140.8  1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
 145    0    0.000 1  14.29   0   0.000
 146.7  1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
 160    0    0.000 2  28.57   0   0.000
 167.6  0    0.000 2  28.57   0   0.000
 225    0    0.000 1  14.29   0   0.000
 258    0    0.000 1  14.29   0   0.000
 275.8  0    0.000 0   0.00   3  21.429
 301    0    0.000 0   0.00   1   7.143
 304    0    0.000 0   0.00   1   7.143
 318    0    0.000 0   0.00   1   7.143
 350    0    0.000 0   0.00   1   7.143
 351    0    0.000 0   0.00   1   7.143
 360    0    0.000 0   0.00   2  14.286
 400    0    0.000 0   0.00   1   7.143
 440    0    0.000 0   0.00   1   7.143
 460    0    0.000 0   0.00   1   7.143
 472    0    0.000 0   0.00   1   7.143
 All   11  100.000 7 100.00  14 100.000

[[3]]

     cyl                             
     4           6         8         
 hp  n   Percent n Percent n  Percent
 52   1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
 62   1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
 65   1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
 66   2   18.182 0   0.00   0   0.000
 91   1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
 93   1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
 95   1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
 97   1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
 105  0    0.000 1  14.29   0   0.000
 109  1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
 110  0    0.000 3  42.86   0   0.000
 113  1    9.091 0   0.00   0   0.000
 123  0    0.000 2  28.57   0   0.000
 150  0    0.000 0   0.00   2  14.286
 175  0    0.000 1  14.29   2  14.286
 180  0    0.000 0   0.00   3  21.429
 205  0    0.000 0   0.00   1   7.143
 215  0    0.000 0   0.00   1   7.143
 230  0    0.000 0   0.00   1   7.143
 245  0    0.000 0   0.00   2  14.286
 264  0    0.000 0   0.00   1   7.143
 335  0    0.000 0   0.00   1   7.143
 All 11  100.000 7 100.00  14 100.000
```

Comment: @Lin Gresky How would I apply this using sub-setting (avoid calling on hp and disp explicitly).

Comment: @NewBee -- see updated answer, where I've automated the generation of tabular tables  with `lapply()`.

Comment: How would I write out the results into a CSV format? I am unable to convert this into a data frame to export it from R...

Comment: @NewBee - Please prepare a new question that illustrates what you ultimately want to do with the data, including the expected output. If you're trying to prepare data for downstream processing, an alternate approach might be preferable to the one I used to answer this question.  Also post a comment here that includes the URL to your new question, so I can review & respond. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One way is this, although I don't know if you need the cyl column:

```
by(mtcars[,2:4],mtcars$cyl,lapply,tabyl)
```

Or a tidy way, (I think the list part can be improved) :

```
out = mtcars[,2:4] %>% 
mutate(id=cyl) %>% 
group_by(id) %>% summarize_all(~list(tabyl(.)))

out

# A tibble: 3 x 4
     id cyl              disp              hp               
  <dbl> <list>           <list>            <list>           
1     4 <df[,3] [1 × 3]> <df[,3] [11 × 3]> <df[,3] [10 × 3]>
2     6 <df[,3] [1 × 3]> <df[,3] [5 × 3]>  <df[,3] [4 × 3]> 
3     8 <df[,3] [1 × 3]> <df[,3] [11 × 3]> <df[,3] [9 × 3]> 

out %>% filter(id==4) %>% pull(hp)
[[1]]
   . n    percent
  52 1 0.09090909
  62 1 0.09090909
  65 1 0.09090909
  66 2 0.18181818
  91 1 0.09090909
  93 1 0.09090909
  95 1 0.09090909
  97 1 0.09090909
 109 1 0.09090909
 113 1 0.09090909
```

Comment: Thank you! I was hoping to see cyl as a column within each tabyl output, such as when you run this. mtcars %>% tabyl(hp,cyl)

Comment: Ok i edited the answer.. hmm i think the structure is a bit nasty for tidy. let me try and put it into a tibble